# Wagtail SnippetChooserBlock in Streamfield

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

I am having some trouble getting the values from a snippet, that I have included into a streamfield using a Snippet Chooser Block.

BioSnippet:

```
@register_snippet
class BioSnippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = RichTextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name='Bio Image'
    )
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('job_title'),
        FieldPanel('bio'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('contact_email'),
        FieldPanel('contact_phone'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]
```

Bio Streamfield Definitions:

```
class BioInline(StructBlock):
    bio = SnippetChooserBlock(BioSnippet)

class BioBlock(StructBlock):
    overall_title = CharBlock(required=False)
    bios = ListBlock(BioInline())
```

This all works, but when I get to the template, I cannot seem to access the values of the snippet

```
{% for b in child.value.bios %}
    {{ b }}

    <hr>
    {{ b.name }}

{% endfor %}
```

the {{ b }} tag outputs:

```
bio
Sales Team
```

However {{ b.name }} outputs nothing.  Neither does {{ b.values.name }} or any other permutation I can guess at.  I suspect the values are just not being pulled down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bios` here is defined as a list of `BioInline` values, and so `b` in your template would be a `BioInline` value - which has a single property, `bio` (giving you the actual `BioSnippet` object). To get the name, you'd therefore have to use: `{{ b.bio.name }}`.

I don't think the `BioInline` object is actually gaining you anything though - you could instead define `BioBlock` as:

```
class BioBlock(StructBlock):
    overall_title = CharBlock(required=False)
    bios = ListBlock(SnippetChooserBlock(BioSnippet))
```

which would make `bios` a list of `BioSnippet`s - `{{ b.name }}` would then work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use self.bios

In blocks.py you have to import the Snippet model (should have this allready):

```
from thebioapp.models import BioSnippet
```

And then use this model in the template itself

```
{% for b in self.bios %}
    {{ b }}

    <hr>
    {{ b.name }}

{% endfor %}
```

The post is old, but as Wagtail is growing in popularity, I hope this will benefit others!